# convert single index pandas data frame to multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a data frame with following structure:

```
df.columns
Index(['first_post_date', 'followers_count', 'friends_count',
       'last_post_date','min_retweet', 'retweet_count', 'screen_name',
       'tweet_count',  'tweet_with_max_retweet', 'tweets', 'uid'],
        dtype='object')
```

Inside the *tweets* series, each cell is another data frame containing all the *tweets* of an user.

```
df.tweets[0].columns
Index(['created_at', 'id', 'retweet_count', 'text'], dtype='object')
```

I want to convert this data frame to a multi-index frame, essentially by breaking the cell containing tweets. One index will be the *uid*, and another will be the *id* inside *tweet*.

How can I do that?

[link to sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uaki7ks6gv01ie/sample.json?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

One way to pull the embedded dataframe up into the main dataframe and build a multi index is like:

#### Code:

```
def expand_tweets(tweets_df):
    tweets = []
    for uid, sub_df in tweets_df.set_index('uid').tweets.iteritems():
        sub_df['uid'] = uid
        tweets.append(sub_df)
    return pd.concat(tweets).merge(
        tweets_df.drop('tweets', axis=1).reset_index(),
        how='outer', on='uid').set_index(['uid', 'id'])
```

#### How:

1. Pull all of the tweet dataframes out of main dataframe using `uid` as an index, and `concat()` them together with their `uid`.
2. Then merge the main dataframe into the concatenated tweets dataframe.
3. Set the desired index.

#### Test Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('test.json') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(f))
df['tweets'] = df.tweets.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x))

print(expand_tweets(df).text.head())
```

#### Results:

```
uid         id                
1153859336  655060275025047552    Article on my new Haunted Stevenage book Paran...
            653912439940120576    Big thank you to @bobfmuk for interviewing me ...
            643709869908996096    Another interesting non-toadstool tweet today,...
            547107275681579008    @sisax67 Thanks, Simon. All the best to you &a...
            546693940024733696    Paul Adams @SkySportsDarts The Wanderer from W...
Name: text, dtype: object
```